# Installation of Booked Tables into dockered mysql with null user

Tags: mysql

the error shown "Access denied for user ''@'192.168.99.1" 
Full error : 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'192.168.99.1' (using password: NO) in /Users/weikeunglam/Documents/Sites/booked/Presenters/Install/Installer.php on line 230

I wanted to grant permission but i couldnt create a '' user....pls help 
Note: I can connect to mysql through mysqlworkbench

Comment: mysqld -u root -p then hit enter then  enter {Your password}

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know how to send that command to the container , I have tried docker compose but it threw error saying it didn't understand the -u option , or -- username option for mysqld